# Zurb Foundation: compile Sass with my own overrides (e.g. set table width always 100%)

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Not a designer so Sass is really new to me. I'm working on customizing Zurb's Foundation to suit my own tastes but I'm stumped on customizing stuff outside of simple variables (which I configure in `_settings.scss` partial).

So the rule is: I'm not allowed to modify any other file other than my own `_custom.scss` partial and the `_settings.scss` partial. So for an example, I don't like how the tables aren't stretched to 100% width like in Twitter Bootstrap and there is no variable in the `_settings.scss` partial how would I customize it rather than modifying `_tables.scss`? Is it possible to extend the table mixin to incorporate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple options to do that.

to work with Foundation you should consider manipulating the "app.scss" file.
I'd create a new file called _table.scss (not in the Foundation folder), with this content:

```
 table
 {
     width: 100%;
 }
```

Then go to the app.scss and add

```
@import "table";
```

Compass can now merge your definition into one css-file.

Or you create a second CSS-file that you load after the app.css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/table.css">
```

But that is rather bad for your performance and maintainability.

If you are new to scss, you should know that the underscore in front of the file name is used to define Partials (http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials). If you create a new scss-file without an underscore before the name, compass will create a new .css file for that scss file.

Another way to extend the `@mixin table` would be simply to include it:

```
@import
    "foundation/components/tables";

table {
    @include table();
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: So `app.css` would contain all of foundation's css and then add `width: 100%` to the table mixin?

Comment: That is right @thwa at first the default rules are defined and you override just the things you want without alterin the framework code.